# Как реализовать 2 функции создания и удаления объекта Unity через UI интерефейс

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: Пример работы]

Я новичок в Unity. Мне необходимо по кнопке "New Object" создавать копию шара (Rigidbody 2D), а по кнопке "Delete Object" удалять последний созданный. Подскажите, как лучше всего реализовать подобный функционал.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine;

public class UIObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D circlePreFab;
    public List<Rigidbody2D> copiesOfCircles = new List<Rigidbody2D>();
    void Start()
    {
        circlePreFab = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void Create()
    {
        Rigidbody2D circleClone = Instantiate(circlePreFab);
        copiesOfCircles.Add(circleClone);
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        Rigidbody2D circleClone = copiesOfCircles[copiesOfCircles.Count - 1];
        Destroy(circleClone);
        copiesOfCircles.RemoveAt(copiesOfCircles.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: [раз](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Button-clicked.html), [два](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html). Храните созданные объекты в списке, например `List<GameObject>`, по кнопке вызывайте `Destroy` у последнего и удаляйте из списка.

Comment: @aepot отредактровал собственный вопрос, клоны объекта создаёт, но удалять не хочет ;(

Comment: Я не спец, но мне кажется, уничтожать надо GameObject `Destroy(circleClone.gameObject);`

Comment: @aepot спасибо огромное!! как отблагодарить через комментарий?

Comment: Оформил ответом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уничтожать надо `GameObject`, я полагаю.

```
Destroy(circleClone.gameObject);
```

[Справка Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) говорит о том, что если уничтожать компонент, в вашем случае `Rigidbody2D`, то уничтожается только компонент на объекте, а не сам объект.